# Unable to get user id with token by django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, authorization, token

I am using django Django=2.1.7 and rest framework djangorestframework=3.9.2 This is my url for login

```
path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
```

After authentication I got token but I need user id too. I tried to override the post method of rest_framework.authtoken.views.py file with the following code

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        context = {
            'token': token.key,
            'user': user.id
        }
        return Response({'context': context})
```

Please help me figure out how to get user id with the token. This is my college project.

**Note: I find many answers on stack overflow but none is helpful.**

Comment: That is another Python package. Why don't you provide full context? Incomplete information, incomplete answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [Django RestFramework token authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) in order to use authentication. Here you can see how to authenticate, however if you want to use token authentication by default for all views you should add it in `settings.py` file as :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       ...
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       ...
    ),
}
```

or you should add it manually to views which requires token authentication. And in this views you can get authenticated user as `request.user` or `self.request.user`.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class ViewSetName(ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```